# iOS 5: UIWebView not copying text from Excel files

Tags: ios, uiwebview, copy, xlsx, uipasteboard

I used UIPasteboardChangedNotification to detect when a user Copy a highlighted text

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveClipBoardNotification:) 
                                                 name:@"UIPasteboardChangedNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}
```

This works perfectly on iOS 6, however appPasteBoard.string returns nil on iOS 5

```
-(void)receiveClipBoardNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSLog(@"%@", appPasteBoard.string);
}
```

This problem occurs only with xls and xlsx files. It works well with other types of files such as pdf, docx, pptx, rtf, pages, key, etc.